Configuring a WireGuard Server to Forward Each Client's Traffic Through a Local SOCKS5 Proxy for Different External IP Addresses?
How to configure the WireGuard server to forward each client's traffic to a monitored port on the local machine, and this monitored port will send traffic out through a SOCKS5 proxy, thereby achieving different external IP addresses for each client.
I tested this rule, and the machine received forwarded traffic, but it seems to be wrong:
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -s 10.8.0.2 -p tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 172.18.0.1:18999

iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -s 10.8.0.2 -p udp -j DNAT --to-destination 172.18.0.1:18999

The traffic received by the listening port


What you probably need is some kind of "socksifier" that provides you a tun interface (for each socks server). Then you'll probably need to leverage policy / source-based routing (with extra/alternate route tables) for each client. (Or, at least provide some information on which "transparent" socksifier you are trying to use.)
